# How to translate string text to amount in magento

Tags: admin, currency, conversion

I have develop a payment gateway where an admin can put their invoice fee. Problem is this, when user update fee 15.20 then its OK but when user insert price as 15,20 then its make problem means he is using comma(,) as decimal separated and dot(.) as thousand separated.

Please anyone suggests how to parse string 15.123,98 to 15,123.98 is their any magento function to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function format from the model 'directory/currency'. This will try to format any string as a currency. The second parameter is an array that can contain some cool features like `'display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL` if you do not want to show the symbol.

```
echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format(
    '15.123,98',
    array(),
    false
);
```

The options you can add to the display array can be found in /lib/Zend/Currency.php and are:

```
NO_SYMBOL, USE_SYMBOL, USE_SHORTNAME, USE_NAME
```

Or if you want to load the currency format from a store you can do the following.

```
$currency = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseCurrency();
echo $currency->format('15.123,98');
```